# jquery blockui on same object with multiple ajax calls?

Tags: jquery, jquery-blockui

I have a 2 ajax calls which could take various times to complete. I call them in "parallel", ie. fire off two ajax requests in code.

How can i use blockUI to appear on start and completion of BOTH calls. I don't want two masks on the same thing i'm trying to block (that's a hack im doing now). Prefer not to use global states etc as one could run into locking issues?

thanks,

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: two masks on the same thing of course and the solution below i already know. Thought there was someting more elegant?

Answer (score 0):

Use some variable to store block status

```
  var isBlocked = false;
  //First ajax call.
  $.ajax({type: "POST",
          url: "/some/url1",
          data: {"param1":value1},
          beforeSend: function() {
            if(!isBlocked) {
              $('#my_div').block({message: null});
              isBlocked = true;
            }
          },
          success: function(data) {
            // code
          },
          error: function(request, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            // code
          },
          complete: function(request, textStatus){
            if(isBlocked){
              $('#my_div').unblock();
              isBlocked = false;
            }
          }
  });

  //Second ajax call.
  $.ajax({type: "POST",
          url: "/some/url2",
          data: {"param1":value1},
          beforeSend: function() {
            if(!isBlocked) {
              $('#my_div').block({message: null});
              isBlocked = true;
            }
          },
          success: function(data) {
            // code
          },
          error: function(request, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            // code
          },
          complete: function(request, textStatus){
            if(isBlocked){
              $('#my_div').unblock();
              isBlocked = false;
            }
          }
  });
```